# Group/algebraic structure on the surface of manifolds?

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, low-dimensional-topology

I've looked around quite a while for an answer to this but I have yet to find any explanation what so ever nevertheless a simplistic one.

I know It's homology (as well as if a surface is open or closed) that "gives algebraic structure" to the geometric surface of manifolds but I have no clue in what way how, so what I seek is a simple understanding of that how.

How is algebraic structure given to the surface of a manifold?
What of homology gives algebraic structure to the surface of a manifold?
Is there a theorem or result for this?

Comment: I’m not entirely sure what you mean by adding algebraic structure to a manifold. Homology doesn’t add a new structure on manifolds per se. It’s a _functor_ i.e. something that sends manifolds to groups, and maps between them to homomorphisms. In contrast, you can add smooth structures on manifolds, and this is adding a differential structure. This does add new functors to the manifold, such as de Rham cohomology. Homology doesn’t let you do “algebra on the manifold”. You might want to look at topological groups or Lie groups for manifolds with algebraic structure on them.

Comment: Well, It's like how the surface of a Torus is always an Abelian Group or a Sphere a ring. I thought certain topological structure assured It's surface would always have  algebraic structure regardless of the geometry of it and homology was always the tool to assure that. I meant algebra that already exists based off of the topological structure, would it be right then to say that just isn't a thing and my assumption that it was, was wrong? If so why is a Torus almost always refered to as an Abelian Group in context to It's surface?

Comment: I guess to simplify my question, what makes a Torus' surface an abelian group? Unless I'm just asking the wrong question all together. :)

Comment: $S^1$ is the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^2\cong\mathbb{C}$, so inherits an algebraic structure as the kernel of the norm homomorphism $\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $z\mapsto |z|^2$. The torus is $S^1\times S^1$, so has an algebraic structure as the product of groups. I think your real question is 'how does one give manifold structure to an algebraic object?', and this is the focus of the theory of Lie groups. This has nothing to do with manifold homology, however.

Comment: The torus and _certain_ spheres are examples of Lie groups. The only spheres with Lie group structure are $S^0, S^1, S^3$. This is separate from homology. I’m not sure what ring structure exists on a sphere. There are some relations between Lie groups and homology (for example Lie groups are always orientable so have non-trivial top-dimensional homology) but one doesn’t determine the other. The torus _is_ an Abelian group but that’s just because it’s the quotient of $\mathbb{R}^2$ by the action of the integer lattice.

Comment: Thank you so much Tyrone and Osama, that is all I needed. :) I will look into Lie Groups further into the future when I am more well-studied.